# How to check properties with Hibernate efficiently?

Tags: java, sql, performance, hibernate, orm

We are using Hibernate for Object/Relational Mapping. This works fine when loading entire entities. However, often I face the problem that I simply want to check a single attribute or `COUNT()` table entries based on a certain criteria. For sake of performance, I use Native SQL in those cases instead of loading several objects from database and checking their properties in Java. But having plain SQL queries is error-prone and I feel like it violates the idea of ORM.

So I wonder, is there any ORM approach to check single attributes with Hibernate efficiently?

**Example:** Let's assume we have two entity beans `Order` and `OrderPosition`. We want to check, if an order is partly delivered (i.e. `COUNT(OrderPositions WHERE isDelivered = true) > 0`).

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    private long id;
    private List<OrderPosition> orderPositions;

    // ...
}

@Entity
public class OrderPosition {
    private isDelivered = false;

    // ...
}
```

(Code is simplified for readability.)

Comment: ... HQL / JPQL also supports count queries and you're free to select individual properties rather than entire object graphs. Heck you can do a select new object and have Hibernate stick the properties directly in a VO object if you want.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#Aggregation_functions